# NestedScrollView containing content smaller than screen height Scrolls in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to implement the ActionBar scrolling-with-content behavior introduced with Material Design.

I'm trying to do it on a page which contains a `SlidingTabLayout` and a `ViewPager` as a direct sibling to the `AppBarLayout`. I have got to the current state by adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `ViewPager`.

This has resulted in two peices of unexpected behavior:

1) When the `Fragment` content is smaller than the screen height, vertical scrolling still occurs (`AppBarLayout` contents shouldn't scroll if it's neighbor doesn't scroll).

2) Scrolling *doesn't* happen when the scroll touch event starts on a touchable child element. **Edit:** this issue is described here [Issue 182549](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182549)

You can see on this gif that the first ScrollEvent on Page0 displays issue 1 and the second scroll on Page0 shows issue 2. (Strangely, issue 2 isn't in evident on Page1).

[image]

I have created an entire demo project which you can find on GitHub which exhibits this bug: https://github.com/gwoodhouse/TestApplication

For quick reference, my Activities xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:background="@color/teal"
                                                 android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="@color/teal"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <com.example.graemecastle.testapplication.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/slidingTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Fragments XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:text=">"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Extra Buttons Added Here to show how view's which should scroll scroll correctly -->
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So far capturing the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` has not made it clear to me what is happening. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to disable nested scrolling when the NestedScrollView does not have enough content to scroll, i.e canScrollVertically()?

Comment: No, but, I'm pretty sure the incorrect scrolling isn't happening from the NestedScrollView, but by the CoordinatorLayout. It would also mean measuring the Fragment Contents Height on the fly and disabling programatically (and, in cases where contents grows and shrinks, reenabling). Basically, even if that did work it wouldn't be a viable solution. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: I found nice gist https://gist.github.com/MaciejKaras/02bff315f00b87d80467a470424f22c3 and made some changes (with change to kotlin, and removing dependency on Toolbar) here: https://gist.github.com/v-mas/3d5b8692cd95fbf0a69f778b9b790ea4